# Animation of text in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-animation

I'm trying to animate the alpha value of the text in a tableview cell. It works well when I animate all cells. But when I try to just animate a few nothing happens.

I have sub classed the cells and call a custom cell method with:

```
[cell setCellWithObject:customObject animate:YES];
```

And the method:

```
- (void) setCellWithObject:(CustomObject *) obj animate:(BOOL) anim{
    textlabel.text = obj.name;
    if (anim){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5.0];
        [self.textlabel setAlpha:0.4];
        [self.textlabel setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    }
}
```

Any advice?

EDIT:

This code actually works. Turns out that i reloaded the tableview twice. Thats why the animation didn't show.

My misstake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this code works!

I was just beeing stupid setting up the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You want to put one of your 'setAlpha' calls outside the animation code. e.g.

```
    [self.textlabel setAlpha:1];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5.0];
    [self.textlabel setAlpha:0.4];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Not the problem though, it works when I animate all cells.